# Book in which a man who's been poisoned is saved by a princess using a snake that absorbs the poison

Tags: story-identification, novel

I need the name of a book. I read the first of a series 20 years ago.

The story is about a young man of the streets who falls in love with a princess, he is poisoned and she saves him by making her people feed him a snake that absorbs the poison and saves him. This though means he can never get drunk or be poisoned.

Comment: If the princess was a priestess, and the book was not the first of a series, the question describes a part of the plot of Hugh Cook's fourth book of A Chronicle of an Age of Darkness.  That book is the Walrus and the Warwolf and tells the story of Drake Douay and his adventures as he pursues the love of Zanya Kliedervaust....

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1720859.The_Walrus_And_The_Warwolf